# Did Andrea Thomas become Isis or just gain her powers?

Tags: dc, tv, shazam

In the CBS television show *Isis* (later *Secrets of Isis*), did Andrea Thomas *become* the goddess Isis when she invoked the power of the Tutmose Amulet, or did she merely gain the powers of Isis, and because she has the superhuman powers of Isis then adopt the new superhero name “Isis” as her alter-ego?

When Andrea turned into Isis, did she turn into the goddess Isis, or a superhero having the goddess Isis’ powers who also called herself Isis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [main credits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdBRLV6PGro):

> "With this amulet, you (queen Hatshepsut of Egypt) and your descendants are endowed by the goddess
> Isis with the powers of ..."

It sounds like "merely gain the powers of"